# Blank return value( sum of two numbers)

Tags: methods, return-value

```
public class Sum {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    add(19, 21);

  }

  public static int add(int number1, int number2) {
    int sum = number1 + number2;
    return sum;

  }

}
```

Why is not returning the value  40 from the sum and is there a better way to write this method.

Comment: How do you know it is not returning 40? What is it returning?

Comment: nothing in Visual Studio code